# How to arrange div elements in vertical columns like on Pinterest?

Tags: html

Since a few years ago I see some blogs like [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/rachelled/healthy-breakfast-recipes/) which display posts of different heights in columns with no horizontal alignment. I don't understand how they achieve that. Do they use Javascript? If so, do they use some jQuery plugin?

Comment: I dont know about Pinterest in particular, but I do know that some blogs use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for dynamic grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different divs, both vertical, then they shouldn't try to horizontally align themselves. For example of you made a single div that would enclose both columns, making it the proper width and height, and then nested two more divs inside of it with a width around 50%, then they would not align horizontally. Outside of that, there shouldn't be anything trying to horizontally align the elements of those divs. If this doesn't answer your question, please post the code.